# JSF entity conversion error: rich suggestionbox Conversion Error setting value '*' for 'null Converter'

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, seam2

I am using **rich:suggestionbox**.

- Select a suggestion from the suggestion box
- Then save my form
- It raises the validation error saying `rich suggestionbox Conversion Error setting value '568-UNIMED-2005' for 'null Converter'`.

I need help with

- What is wrong with my code?
- How to fix the issue?

Here is my `LcInfo` bean

```
@AutoCreate
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name("lcInfo")
@Entity
@Table(name="lc_info")
public class LcInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    private ItemIndentMast itemIndentMastBean;

    public LcInfo() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to ItemIndentMast
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="item_indent_mast", nullable=false)
    public ItemIndentMast getItemIndentMastBean() {
        return this.itemIndentMastBean;
    }

    public void setItemIndentMastBean(ItemIndentMast itemIndentMastBean) {
        this.itemIndentMastBean = itemIndentMastBean;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) return true;
        if (object == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != object.getClass()) return false;
        LcInfo other = (LcInfo) object;
        return id.equals(other.id);
    }


}
```

Here is my XHTML source with a **rich:suggestionbox**.

```
            <h:inputText value="#{lcInfo.itemIndentMastBean}" id="itemIndentMastBean" required="true"/>
            <rich:suggestionbox for="itemIndentMastBean"
                suggestionAction="#{lcInfoController.suggestion}"
                var="result" 
                fetchValue="#{result}"
                minChars="3"
                nothingLabel="No capitals found" >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Select Indent Number" style="font-size: 10px; padding-left: 5px"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{result}" />
                </h:column>
            </rich:suggestionbox>
```

Here is the controller code how suggestions are loaded from controller

```
@Name("lcInfoController")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@AutoCreate
public class LcInfoController {


    public List<ItemIndentMast> suggestion(Object query) {
        String queryText = query.toString();
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(queryText) || queryText.length() < 3) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        return itemIndentMastService.filterIndent(queryText+"%");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the input recieve a string value and not a bean :
change

```
value="#{lcInfo.itemIndentMastBean}",
```

to

```
  value="#{lcInfo.someString}",
```

JSF does not know how handle your ItemIndentMast BEAN.
alternatevly you can create a converter for that bean (convert string to bean)
http://www.javabeat.net/tips/70-create-simple-custom-converter-implementation.html

Comment: "JSF does not know how to display your ItemIndentMast BEAN" what did u mean with that? Will be glad if you please explain more.

Comment: jsf gets  string in the  <h:inputText .. > and tries to convert it to a itemIndentMastBean object , but itemIndentMastBean is not a string so it fails. a  <h:inputText .. >  must be attached to strings, if you want tot attach it to an object you must have a converter from the input string to the object

Comment: custom converter sounds like a nice option. I will try it when I get the chance, and let u know.

Comment: trying hard to add a converter. As I my application is on top of seam and tried all possible combination to do it seam way. In the end outcome is, my server get shutdown. So u can understand :-S

Answer (score 2):

This is what I  came up with in the end: [Seam: Creating a custom converter](http://kowsercse.com/2011/09/03/seam-creating-a-custom-converter/)